# What part of speech is "run"?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

A JobInstance refers to the concept of a logical job run.

In the above sentence, is the final word "run" a noun? and which word does the adjective "logical" modify? job or job run?

Is the word "job run" a compound noun?

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing more about the system. But you might get somewhere by asking whether logical jobs are run, or whether jobs can be run physically.

Comment: Try Googlr searches on "logical job", "job run" and "logical job run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *A JobInstance refers to the concept of* ***[a logical job run].***

The phrase "a logical job run" seems to be a noun phrase, due to the presence of the article "a".

And so, "run" is probably the head noun--or functioning as the head of that noun phrase.

Often it is the case that the two modifiers--"logical" and "job"--are either both modifying the word "run" (#A), or else are together a phrase which then modifies the word "run" (#B). That is, it's parsed as one of the following:

- A: "a [logical [job [run]]]" - - [stacked modification]
- B: "a [ [logical job] [run]]" - - [submodification]

Version #A is interpreted as: a "run" that is a "job" (modifier) and that is also "logical" (modifier). That is, "a job run" and "a logical run" should both make sense.

Version #B is interpreted as: a "run" that is a "logical job" (modifier phrase).

There is a third possibility:

- C: "a [logical [job-run]]"

where version #C is interpreted as a "job-run" that is "logical" (modifier). (The hyphen might or might not be optional.)

You would know better than me as to which interpretation is the more reasonable one.

ADDED: Don't let the possibility of "job" being a noun mislead you. For look at the following example, where "brick" is also a noun:

- "a [new [brick [wall]]]" - - [stacked modification]

Here, the head of the noun phrase is "wall". It has two separate modifiers: "new" and "brick". This can be seen due to the acceptability here of the following phrases: *"a new wall", "a brick wall", "a wall"*. And so, the noun "brick" is merely a modifier in "a new brick wall".

Comment: I agree: it's a noun, used the way engineers more generally talk about "test runs" of rockets, etc. If you want to know whether A, B, or C is the correct parsing, I suggest you refer to the wider documentation, particularly other classes in the library and the inheritance hierarchy for the class, both for fragments of the phrase and also for contrasting phrases. Are there, for example, "Logical Jobs", or "Physical Job Runs".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is standard computerese terminology: A "run" is one complete execution of the program or process being described, and thus is a noun. Whether "logical" modifies "job" or "job run" isn't clear from this quote, but the three words together can be treated as a compound noun.